# Why for loop and arr[5000]= {0, } changes unrealated variable in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, variables, printing

When I run this code, (tested on Online C Compiler and OnlineGDB)

for(int i=1;i<=5000;i++) makes selfNumSum to 5002. 
(This for loop doesn't have any codes to change selfNumsum variable)

I found somethings that change selfNumSum variable..

1. arr[5001] = {0, };

> when I delete "= {0, }", it prints 0 normally.

2. for(int i=1;i<=something;i++)

> if something is 4976~, for loop makes selfNumSum to 5002. else if something ~4975, it prints 0 normally.

But I don't know why these are related to selfNumSum. (I want to know why it changes this)

(Why = {0, } change other variable? and why unrelated for loop changes selfNumSum?)
Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[5001] = {0, };
int a;
int b;
int num;
int oneNum;
int sum=0;
int selfNumSum=0;

int selfNumber(int a, int b) {
printf("init = %d\n", selfNumSum);

/*This for loop makes selfNumSum to 5002*/
for(int i=1;i<=5000;i++) {
    //printf("i = %d, selfnumsum = %d\n", i, selfNumSum);
    if(sum<=5000) {
        num=i;
        sum=i;
        while(num>=1) {
            oneNum=num%10;
            num=num/10;
            sum+=oneNum;
        }
        sum+=num;
        arr[sum] = sum;    
    }
}

printf("selfNumSum = %d\n", selfNumSum);

for(int i=a;i<=b;i++) {
    if(arr[i]==0) {
        printf("+%d\n", i);
        selfNumSum+=i;
    }
}

return selfNumSum;
}


int main() {
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    selfNumSum = selfNumber(a, b);
    printf("%d", selfNumSum);
}
```

Input

```
1 10
```

Output

```
init = 0
selfNumSum = 5002
+1
+3
+5
+7
+9
5027
```

If I make selfNumSum-5002 or delete ={0, }, it will print normally, but I want to know why these change selfNumSum?
(Sorry about my bad English..)

Comment: `sum+=num; arr[sum] = sum;` The value of `sum`  becomes greater than `5000` and thus results in overflowing the buffer when used as an index. If you don't believe it then just add code to check for that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared arr[5001] before selfNumSum so this implies you you modifying arr[sum] where sum >= 5001.  I.e. out of bounds, and you just happen to overwrite an unrelated variable.

Run the code through a debugger and set a data break point on selfNumSum (gdb: `watch selfNumSum`) or a conditional breakpoint on the `arr[sum] = sum` line when `sum >= 5001`.  You can also add add a debug statement to print sum before you do `arr[sum] = sum;` to verify sum >= 5001.

I did the latter and found the line `sum+=oneNum;` causes sum to become 5002 with the input you gave on the later iteration of the lop.  Also, note that `sum+=num;` doesn't do anything as `num` is always 0 after the while loop.

Comment: Sorry, Can I ask you why it overwrites an unrelated variable in if(sum<=5000)? 
I think if(sum<=5000) can make the max size of array 5000.
(I am very bad at English, So I can't understand your answer well :( )

Comment: arr[sum] is the same as *(arr + sum) so arr + sum is address in memory.  if sum is >= 5001 you are writing outside the array itself.  What is stored there is other variables like selfNumSum.  You can `printf("%p", &selfNumSum)` to see that address and compare it address of arr with `printf('%p', arr)`.

Comment: Why is sum >= 5001?  I added `printf("sum = %d\n", sum);` before `arr[sum] = sum;` and used the input 1 10 and last iteration gave me `sum = 5002`.  The code is then doing arr[5002] and that is out of bounds.

Comment: `num` is always zero after the while loop, so the problem is `sum+=oneNum;`